# postman ECONNRESET error with async method (even though I have my return model)

Tags: c#, .net, api, postman

```
public async Task<BillerResp> BillerRespAsync(BillerReq data)
{
    string sessionID = await sp.GetUserSessionID(\*\*\*\*\*"*", "**", "***\*");

    BillerResp resp = new BillerResp();
    Connectpr connector = sp[sessionID];
    BillDetails bill = await connector.GetBill(data.acNumber, data.billerId);

    if (bill != null)
    {
        resp.name = bill.BillerName;
        resp.accountNumber = bill.accountNumber;
        resp.currency = bill.currency;
        resp.balanceAmount = (int)bill.balanceAmount;
    }
    else
    {
        resp.ErrorCode = -1;
        resp.ErrorMsg = "Bill not found.";
    }
    return resp;
}
```

When I send a request from postman, I get ECONNRESET error from postman, even though my return model is filled in VS.
I wonder if is caused by async method?

SSL is disabled, I have tried to disable request header connection keep-alive, I've reboot IIS and several things but it didnt work.

---

```
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: de07373f-b339-41f7-9ae7-649591bb32ed
Host: localhost:44327
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br


{
    "data":{
     "prijava": "*******",
        "signature": "*******",
        "acNumber":"*******",
        "billerId":"*******"
    }
}
```

my request data is above

Comment: Can you provide the request data sent from Postman?  I assume the code above is method that's running when you make the request on your service?

Comment: Just checking the basics, are you sending anything in the Request Body?  Your method is expecting a type of _BillerReq_ however you've not show that this is being sent.

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: thanks everyone, it's my first question post I've edited my question.

Comment: Biller req is shown in data, i can get my return method in VS code but not in postman. @NickScotney

Comment: @Feozkefe Just checking, in the Body tab in postman, are you set to the _raw_ content type selector?

Comment: @NickScotney yes it is raw Json